# Trying to convert Date formatter type (from time picker) to Integer

Tags: ios, swift, datetimepicker, var

having a bit of trouble here, im getting the current time from a date picker called amPicker_out

I'm using date formatter to just get the minutes
I need to convert those two digits of time to an integer.
When I try to convert it I get this error

> "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of
>   type '(DateFormatter)'"

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
   func getTime()
    {

        let amPickerMinutes = DateFormatter()

        amPickerMinutes.dateFormat = "mm"


      // convert amPickerMinutes to Integer
      let amPickerMinutesInt = Int(amPickerMinutes)

        print(amPickerMinutesInt)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting date formatter object to Int, hence the warning. Need to do something like:

```
    func getTime() {

        let amPickerMinutes = DateFormatter()

        amPickerMinutes.dateFormat = "mm"

        // convert amPickerMinutes to Integer
        let dateString = amPickerMinutes.string(from: amPicker_out.date)
        if let amPickerMinutesInt = Int(dateString) {
            print(amPickerMinutesInt)
        }

        // Prefer using calendar instead 
        let amPickerMinutesInt = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: amPicker_out.date)
        print(amPickerMinutesInt)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert DateTimeFormatter to Int. you have to format some date with this formatter and then cast this value to Int

```
    func getTime(date:Date){

        let amPickerMinutes = DateFormatter()
        amPickerMinutes.dateFormat = "mm"

        let minutes = amPickerMinutes.string(from: date)
        let amPickerMinutesInt = Int(minutes)

        print(amPickerMinutesInt)

    }

getTime(date: Date()) // call your function parsing your date picker value
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answers, all fixed now and I have a greater understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

To get the minutes you have to call `stringFromDate` passing a date

```
let amPickerMinutes = DateFormatter()
amPickerMinutes.dateFormat = "mm"
// convert amPickerMinutes to Integer
let amPickerMinutesInt = Int(amPickerMinutes.string(from: picker.date))!
```

However `Calendar` provides a more convenient API

```
let amPickerMinutesInt = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: picker.date)
```